# How to route for search url reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

My search url will like this:

```
http://localhost/symple/?s=new
```

I do not know how to make route for this url. I use like code below but it seems that it loads homepage route.

```
<Route exact
    path={CelestialSettings.path + '?s:query'}
    render={(props) => <App header={<Header />} main={<Search />} sidebar={<Popular />} feature={<Featurex />} mainbottom={<Categories />} />} />
```

Any suggestion for my question. Thank you so much.